# Ruby JSON.parse returning incorrect data for unicode

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to parse some JSON containing escaped unicode characters using `JSON.parse`.  But on one machine, using `json/ext`, it gives back incorrect values.  For example, `\u2030` should return `E2 80 B0` in UTF-8, but instead I'm getting `01 00 00`.  It fails with either the escaped `"\\u2030"` or the unescaped `"\u2030"`.

```
1.9.2p180 :001 > require 'json/ext'
 => true 
1.9.2p180 :002 > s = JSON.parse '{"f":"\\u2030"}'
 => {"f"=>"\u0001\u0000\u0000"} 
1.9.2p180 :003 > s["f"].encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
1.9.2p180 :004 > s["f"].valid_encoding?
 => true 
1.9.2p180 :005 > s["f"].bytes.map do |x| x; end
 => [1, 0, 0]
```

It works on my other machine with the same version of ruby and similar environment variables.  The Gemfile.lock on both machines is identical, including `json (= 1.6.3)`.  It does work with `json/pure` on both machines.

```
1.9.2p180 :001 > require 'json/pure'
 => true 
1.9.2p180 :002 > s = JSON.parse '{"f":"\\u2030"}'
 => {"f"=>"‰"} 
1.9.2p180 :003 > s["f"].encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
1.9.2p180 :004 > s["f"].valid_encoding?
 => true
1.9.2p180 :005 > s["f"].bytes.map do |x| x; end
 => [226, 128, 176]
```

So is there something else in my environment or setup that could be causing it to parse incorrectly?

Comment: Tip: `s["f"].bytes.to_a`

Comment: What is `'foo'.encoding` on the machine that fails? Do you have an encoding comment at the top of your source code?

Comment: `'foo'.encoding` is `#<Encoding:UTF-8>` on both machines.  I've also reproduced the problem with input that is ASCII-8BIT.  I think it shouldn't matter much, since the escaped version of the input is all 7-bit ASCII.

Answer (score 5):

Recently ran into this same problem, and I tracked it down to [this Ruby bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5888) caused by the declaration of [this buffer](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/02a892e48df92436a07d234c84f4b5cafce8ae3a/ext/json/parser/parser.rl#L417) in Ruby 1.9.2 and how it gets [optimized by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51862). It's fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/63da304fb7c849e675e762c626e074d130d1e715).

You can recompile Ruby with `-O0` or use a newer version of Ruby (1.9.3 or better) to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrade your JSON Gem (at least to 1.6.6) or newest 1.7.1.